# Why does Bash output two lines when redirecting stdout to stderr twice (`>&2` and `>/dev/stderr`)?

Tags: bash

Why does the following output redirection result in two lines being printed?

The `>&2` copies stdout to stderr and `>/dev/stderr` also redirects stdout to stderr.

I expect only a single output line as `echo foo` output is redirected to stderr.

Why don't I see two output lines for: `echo foo >/dev/stderr 2>&1` and `echo foo >/dev/stdout 2>&1`?

```
➜  app git:(python3.10-pipeline) ✗ echo foo >/dev/stderr >&2
foo
foo
➜  app git:(python3.10-pipeline) ✗ echo foo >/dev/stdout >&2
foo
foo
```

Comment: I only see one line.

Comment: @Kusalananda I also don't believe that the part about `copying stderr to stdout (>&2)` (which is mentioned in the original question both in the title and the body) is just a typo, but rather that the OP is actually confused about what get's redirected/copied where. Hence my (now deleted) answer.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký, that _might_ be part of it, but it doesn't really explain the duplication either way

Comment: @MartinHeralecký I took the duplication as the main issue and the mixup about the redirection here or there as a misunderstanding.  The question is "why is the output duplicated?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `bash` shell, redirecting the same stream twice will result in the stream's contents being redirected to the *last* (rightmost) destination.  It is true that if you were to give the `bash` shell the commands that you show, only a single line of output would be generated by each (on the standard error stream).

However, you use the `zsh` shell, not `bash`.  In the `zsh` shell, by default, the shell will treat multiple redirections of the same stream as a request to *duplicate* that stream, as if `tee` had been used.

This means that

```
echo hello >/dev/stderr >&2
```

or

```
echo hello >file1 >file2 >file3
```

which redirects standard output two and tree times, respectively, will duplicate the standard output stream in the same way that

```
echo hello | tee /dev/stderr >&2
```

or

```
echo hello | tee file1 file2 >file3
```

would do.

You can disable this behaviour by unsetting the `MULTIOS` shell option in the shell (`unsetopt MULTIOS`).